# c++ with the if, else if, and else statements on my program? (newbie)

Tags: c++, if-statement

I don't understand looping the if statements or why my program isn't working properly. The program is suppose to mirror your grade depending on your input. Does anyone see why it's not working?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int grade;
    cout << "What grade did you earn in Programming I ?" << endl;
    cin >> grade;
    if (grade = 'A')
        cout << "an A - excellent work !" << endl;
    if (grade = 'B')
        cout << "you got a B - good job" << endl;
    else if (grade = 'C')
        cout << "earning a C is satisfactory" << endl;
    else if (grade = 'D')
        cout << "while D is passing, there is a problem" << endl;
    else if (grade = 'F')
        cout << "you failed - better luck next time" << endl;
    else
        cout << "You did not enter an A,B,C,D or F" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `=` in every condition to `==`

Comment: also change data type from `int` to `char` for grade

Comment: Read a good beginners book. Or, really, *any* beginners book.

Comment: Also, please don't get into the habit of calling if-statements loops. They are conditional statements and have nothing to do with loops at all.

Comment: And you need `else if` in front of the "`B`" branch instead of just `if`, too.

Comment: Just for the inspiration: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ac846707865ee56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the `=` in `if` conditions.

`=` is the assignment operator whereas `==` is the equality comparision operator.

When you assign a value to the `int`, it evaluates to true as well, and so the if condition is also satisfied.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, change the data type from `int` to `char` for grade.